# Webpage not word wrapping

Tags: html, css

I would really like to know why this [web page](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) is not word wrapping in Firefox, Chrome or IE on my computer. I looked at the source through firebug, but couldn't figure it out.

Edit:
Thanks for all the answers, I'm assuming adding the following CSS would be the solution?

```
pre {
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: can you explain more what you want thanks :)

Comment: @sandeep - I think the question is straight forward - he wants to know why the content is not wrapping - the browser displays horizontal scrollbar on long text. See my explanation.

Comment: It is word-wrapping. If you look at the text you'll see that some of the paragraphs contain multiple lines. There is very likely an internal element somewhere that is causing the extra widening. If you right-click in Chrome, you can choose "Inspect Element" to view all of the css styling that is applied to each element. You should probably go line-by-line in your html to see which element is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using a pre tag and a pre(formatted text) is displayed in a fixed-width font. That also means it preserves spaces and line breaks hence the text in the pre tag is too long pushing the page to go beyond the limit of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bcause the code samples are wrapped in `<pre>` tag which by default works same as `white-space:pre` and text will only wrap on line breaks - if you remove all of the code samples out you can see the page will stretch normaly and scrollbars disappear.

See this sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/MTdbH/10/

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your long code view

```
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

I think it's `white-space:pre` preventing the word wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with `<div id="content">` because it dont have a `width`.
If you set width to this div (500px for example) - all will be ok.
I would recommend to you use `float` instead of `position:absolute` for layout (p id="logo", div id="content", div id="nav"). Check this article http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C9/ (CSS Liquid Layout #2.1)

Comment: This has nothing to do with width. If the width was set the scrollbar would still appear when screen size would be <500px (+navbar). And the page is not his - htmldog is probably one of the best html/css reference on web - I would assume they know their html.